# Validation between simulation and the real world

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

this question is maybe more like an open or theoretical one.

As one part of my work with the robot simulation I have to make some tests in the real world as
well as in my simulation to validate the usefullness of my work. We want to use the simulation for further development and tests before we try them on our real hardware.

Maybe you have some proposals for me, you have some experience with this topic yourself
or know some points that I really shouldn't miss. For this purpose I plan to
build a recreation of a simple floor or room in our university in Gazebo as the scope for these tests.

At this point of my work we don't really care about a completely correct physics model or
that our pid parameters would work in reality, as long as we have a simulation that somehow
behaves like our real robot (for it has e.g different engines for the joints).
I was more thinking about something like letting the robots (real and simulation)
drive to a defined position and look at the deviation, put an obstacle in their way and look at
their behaviour etc.

Thanks for your help,

Christoph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4312/validation-between-simulation-and-the-real-world/) by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-09-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-11**:
So, what is your question? For Q&As in general specific questions usually yield a better result in terms of the number and quality of answers.

**Comment by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on 2013-09-23**:
See Nate's comment. Thats the kind of things I had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you don't care about correct physics, just test the high-level behaviors like you mentioned. Checking to see if the robot reaches the same point over the same time period is a good test. You can also check that sensor data matches between real-world and simulation.

Basically, each type of environment and robot is different. You'll have to customize tests for your particular setup.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on 2013-09-23**:
Hey Nate! Thanks for those hints. That are some good things to start with.